Visual Glitch When Opening Menu in React + Ant Design Layout
I'm experiencing a visual glitch when opening the Menu component in my React application that uses Ant Design. Specifically, the issue occurs in a layout with a collapsible sidebar. Here is a brief overview of the relevant code and the problem:

const PageLayout: React.FC<LayoutProps> = (props: LayoutProps) => {
  // component code...
  
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Sider
        trigger={null}
        collapsible
        collapsed={collapsed}
        width={250}
        style={{
          position: windowWidth < 770 ? 'fixed' : 'sticky',
          display: collapsed && windowWidth < 770 ? 'none' : 'block',
        }}
        className="nav-side-bar"
      >
        <div className="btn-collapse-smallscreen">
          <Button
            type="text"
            icon={collapsed ? <MenuUnfoldOutlined /> : <MenuFoldOutlined />}
            onClick={() => {
              dispatch(toggleCollapsed());
            }}
            className="btn btn-mobile"
          />
        </div>
        {!collapsed && (
          <div className="logo">
            <img src={Logo} alt="nora logo" width="100%" />
          </div>
        )}
        <Menu
          theme="light"
          style={{ background: '#ffff' }}
          mode="inline"
          onClick={handleRouteChange}
          selectedKeys={[location.pathname]}
          openKeys={openKeys}
          onOpenChange={handleOpenChange}
          items={routeUrl}
        />
      </Sider>

      <div className="main-content" style={{ width: '100%' }}>
        <Layout>
          <Header style={{ padding: 0, background: colorBgContainer }}>
            {/* Header content */}
          </Header>
          {breadCrumbs.length > 0 && (
            <div style={{ marginLeft: windowWidth < 770 ? '1rem' : '1.5rem' }}>
              <Space style={{ marginTop: 15, marginLeft: 15 }}>
                <Breadcrum itemList={breadCrumbs} />
              </Space>
            </div>
          )}

          <Content
            style={{
              margin: '24px 16px',
              padding: 24,
              height: '100vh',
              marginLeft: windowWidth < 770 ? '1rem' : '1.5rem',
              overflow: 'hidden',
              overflowY: 'scroll',
              overflowX: 'scroll',
              background: colorBgContainer,
              borderRadius: borderRadiusLG,
            }}
          >
            {children}
          </Content>
        </Layout>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  );
};

const MemoizedPageLayout = memo(PageLayout);
MemoizedPageLayout.displayName = 'PageLayout';

export default MemoizedPageLayout;


Issue: When the sidebar menu is closed and opened, there is a noticeable visual glitch on submenu of Entity.
What I've Tried:
Checking the conditionally rendered styles and ensuring they apply as expected.
